# How to return Map based on value of another attribute in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Our model class is like:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Address {

    private Long idDL;

    private String streetName;

    private Long pincode;
    
    private String State;
    
    private String Country;
    
    private Long addressCategory;
    
    private String status;
}
```

And repository class is like:

```
   @Repository
    public interface AddressRepository extends JpaRepository<Address, Long> {
    }
```

we want to return `Map<Long,String>` containing `idDL`as key and `pincode`as value when `status='Y'`in our service layer.
We don't want to write any explicit query using `HQL` or `NativeQuery` etc and want to use something like `findByStatus`.Is there any way to achieve this in spring data jpa?

Comment: *No*, there is no way using method query creation. And even using JPQL I don't think it's possible hardly you get `List<Map.Entry>` I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a instant way of doing this. If you don't want to write any query than maybe default method in interface will be good enough:

```
@Repository
public interface AddressRepository extends JpaRepository<Address, Long> {

    public List<Address> findByStatus(String status);

    default public Map<Long, Long> getMap() {
        return findByStatus("Y").stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Address::getIdDL, Address::getPincode));
    }
}
```